# Can I use @RequestBody with multiple model in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have two models:

```java
// users.java
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {
    
    @MongoId(FieldType.STRING)
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    // ....
}
```

```java
// cars.java
@Document(collection="cars")
public class Cars {
    
    @MongoId(FieldType.STRING)
    private String id;
    private String owner;
    private String type;
    private String year;
}
```

How to collect the data with Spring Rest in controllers like:

```java
@PostMapping("add")
public String save (@RequestBody User user,@RequestBody Cars cars){
    String theUser =  user.getFirstname;
    String theCars = cars.getType;
}
```

I need to save JSON like below:

```json
{
    "firstname": "Smith",
    "type": "kfc",
    // more data blabla ......
}
```

Please tell me if you need more data like my pom.xml or other.

Comment: You want to mix the data of users and cars in a json? Why? I'd rethink that design and maybe create something like `{"user": {"firstname": ...}, "car" : {"type": ...}}`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer your answer is different, they're using string, not model.

Comment: @Thomas so my condition is impossible?

Comment: `@RequestBody annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object` if you would actually read the answers...

Comment: Your condition doesn't make sense and looks like bad design. If you really need to do it that way, can you elaborate why?

Comment: @Thomas im new in spring and this time have to do some test case. Currently i dont have any better option.

Comment: Yes, you can, your json will look like this:

````
{
    "user": {
        "id": "3",
        "firstname": "John",
        [...]
    },
    "cars": {
        "id": "5",
        "owner": ...
        "type": ...
        [...]
    }
}
````

Comment: But I would suggest you to make a DTO with only those two fields that you need.

Comment: This is not an issue with spring but a general one. You should not mix data of 2 objects into one unless you really need to. Of course you could create a class like `UserCar` that contains everything but that looks like bad design too. Just think about what would happen if both users and cars would have a property "age" - in the combined class whose age would it be?

Comment: Okay thank you for all. I will try another way.